# Use awk to get value of the parameter in the array

Tags: bash, awk, grep, journal

journalctl -b showed me log like this:

```
something something somethng
aaa: 0x00000111 bbb: 0x00000222 ccc: 0x00000333 ddd: 0x00000444
something something somethng
```

How to get value of parameter 'ccc'?

For example:

```
journalctl -b | awk '/ccc:/{print $1}'
```

showed first word, but I need to get first word after 'ccc':

```
0x00000333
```

Comment: you keep changing your requirement to make answers fail, nice!

Comment: Sorry, I just wanted to make it more specific

Comment: it's ok, but next time pls try to make the sample data including all kinds of cases when you posted the question.

Comment: Take a look at man journalctl. There is a lot of options (-g or -F perhaps)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `sed`:

```
$ echo "aaa: 0x00000111 bbb: 0x00000222 ccc: 0x00000333 ddd: 0x00000444"|sed 's/.*ccc: \([^ ]*\).*/\1/g'
0x00000333
```

If you really want to use `awk`:

```
$ echo "aaa: 0x00000111 bbb: 0x00000222 ccc: 0x00000333 ddd: 0x00000444"|awk '/ccc:/{s=$0; gsub(".*ccc: ", "", s); gsub(" .*$", "", s); print s}'
0x00000333
```

Comment: Is there possibility to upgrade awk that it can find just one array? 
If journal -b shows more ccc parameters I got long output then

Answer (score 2):

This line will give your the value if the key is `ccc`:

```
journalctl -b|grep -oP 'ccc: \K[^ :]*'
```

e.g.

```
kent$  grep -oP 'ccc: \K[^: ]*'<<<"aaa: 0x00000111 bbb: 0x00000222 ccc: 0x00000333 ddd: adfa"
0x00000333
```

Comment: I like this one!

Comment: It is great, but my poor grep does not have -P